# script to download the attachments from an email having a specific subject

Tags: python, outlook

The following code downloads the attachments from the outlook email having a particular subject line (ADP Files). When i execute the script it generates an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\qwerty\\desktop\\EMAIL ADP\\attachments\\1494075600130_1640807852.xls'`.
What could be the problem?

```
import imaplib
import email
import os

svdir = 'C:\\Users\\rnandipati\\desktop\\EMAIL ADP'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com',993)
mail.login("rnai@jmas.com", "R7!")
mail.select("Inbox")

typ, msgs = mail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "ADP Files")')
msgs = msgs[0].split()

for emailid in msgs:
    resp, data = mail.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")

    email_body = data[0][1]
    m = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)

    if m.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    for part in m.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        filename = part.get_filename()
        if filename is not None:
            sv_path = os.path.join(svdir, filename)
            if not os.path.isfile(sv_path):
                print(sv_path)
                fp = open(sv_path, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? For a start `print(msgs)` before the `for` loop will tell you if you should even expect any results.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have, I tried doing that but it still doesnt give any output.

Comment: You don't even see an empty list? How exactly are you executing this script?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do get an output of emails, but its all encoded in some format. I am executing it through command prompt

Comment: Then why did you say it didn't give any output? Please give a [mcve] that shows precisely where the problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was searching for the wrong string in subject.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The problem now is that its reading the emails but it can't seem to download the files: error displayed below..
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\rnandipati\\desktop\\EMAIL ADP\\attachments\\ADP Files.zip'`
Is it due to the zip file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Its not because of the zip file. I tried doing with just a file attachment, it still shows the same error. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `IF NOT` clause and it should work perfectly :)